# PPPD only works with a specific baudrate

Tags: linux, networking, pppd

Basically, I would like to create PPP to interact Linux with Quectel Modem by using pppd though (editing options/ chat script follow to modem command).

Until now, connection: ppp0<-->/dev/ttyS1 was always successful at every baudrate. Unfortunately, IP and DNS are created at only baudrate 9600 which is default baudrate of serial port. With the else baud rate, error always appear: "LCP: Timeout sending config-request. Connection terminated".

It happens to kernel 3.12. With the same files: option/peer/chatscript/pap-secrets, kernel 3.2 can work as well.

I don't know why... Thanks in advance if there is someone can guide me suggestions...

Comment: I expect you need to set the baudrate of the underlying serial/pseudoserial device, perhaps using the "stty" command.

Comment: Hi @davidgo, thanks for your suggestion. Actually, underlying serial device setting up is correct. After a long time coming back this issue, compare whatever are defined in kernel v3.2 to 3.12, I concluded that we need to set up MRU maximum in PPP configuration which isn't defined in 3.12 but in 3.2. By default, MRU Max=1500 that's why baud rate 9600bps =  1200byte can be successful and 115200bps = 14400byte or higher can't.

Comment: I don't see "LCP timeout during config-request" and the MTU being related; the MTU should only matter after the connection is established. First thing I'd do is debug what actually goes over the port, either by putting a pty pair in between, or by increasing `ppp`'s verbosity. And of course you should be sure that the Quectel modem actually works with other baudrates.

Comment: Hi @dirkt, for sure Quectel modem works with other baudrates that I tested with kernel 3.2. Regarding to MTU/MRU, after ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyS connection is created successful, peer will send config request to modem such as CHAP/PAP authentication challenge, IP address info,.... If MTU or MRU is small, communicated data will be cut into small parts and might be lost... it leads to peer/modem can't receive enough info unit to proceed DNS/... configuration then peer keeps send request until reach timeout as notification: "LCP:..." That's what I guess.

Comment: Wait. You have a working configuration using kernel 3.2 with ppp with different baudrates? Same ppp package, or different versions? Can you downgrade to it (possibly in a VM), to compare it to the current broken variant?

Comment: I tried with: 1. kernel v3.2 & ppp v2.4.5 : work with every baud rate 2. kernel v3.12 & ppp v2.4.5: only work at 9600bps 3. kernel v3.12 & ppp v2.4.7 (current version my system uses): only work with 9600bps. ppp package v2.4.5 and 2.4.7 aren't much different then the only thing is kernel. It seems to the difference between kernel v3.2 and v3.12 is defining PPP_MAXMRU and PPP_MTU and not in header file but they are not use in anywhere. So, I add "mtu 1500" and "mru 65000" in options then it works even all version, packages. Still thinking of kernel...